TI BASIC | How to FIND, COMPARE TO A VARIABLE, and REMOVE an item from a list
My code uses an if loop nested inside a while loop:
(The while is higher up in the code and not useful to show)
:If J=1
:Then
:Z+1->Z
:randInt(-10,10)->U
:U->L₁(Z)
:randInt(-10,10)->V
:U->L₂(Z)
:Pt-On(U,V,3)        <-- I want to remove this Pt at a later point in the code
 :End

I use the variables ( A, B ) to track where the player character is
:If sum(A=L₁ and B=L₂ or B=L₁ and A=L₂)
:Then 
:Stop
:End

^This is the code to end the player
When the player clicks a button with Getkey, I want it to remove some of the points from the screen and variables from the list, so that I can make a way the player can survive (think of it as a laser  that hits space invaders)

